# R - Creating separate columns from distinct row values

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a data table with many columns, but cannot think of a way to do this succinctly (using `dplyr` or something else). Let's consider this data:

```
URL               TERM 
google.com        dog
yahoo.com         cat
bing.com          hamster
google.com        dog
google.com        cat
yahoo.com         cat
bing.com          dog
yahoo.com         cat
```

I would like to end with something like this:

```
URL          dog    cat    hamster
google.com   2      1      0
yahoo.com    0      3      0
bing.com     1      0      1
```

This is something that I can achieve using `for` loops... but I might as well not use R. Basically, I'd like to group by `URL`, create a new column for each unique `TERM` value, wherein each column contains a count of said `TERM` for each `URL`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be seen as a problem of reshaping the data frame from long to wide, which can be achieved in a variety of ways in R. For more info check this [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/).

In your case this can do:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, URL ~ TERM)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two operations going on here: (1) aggregating on both `URL` and `TERM` to produce a count of each such composite key, and (2) reshaping from long to wide format.

In pure base R, you can use a combination of [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) and [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) to do this:

```
reshape(aggregate(num~.,cbind(df,num=1L),sum),dir='w',idvar='URL',timevar='TERM');
##          URL num.cat num.dog num.hamster
## 1 google.com       1       2          NA
## 2  yahoo.com       3      NA          NA
## 3   bing.com      NA       1           1
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple working code . It might not be the best but it is giving the results. I would appreciate some improvement on it. Please find the output below:

```
     bevs <- data.frame(cbind( col1=c("google.com", "yahoo.com","bing.com","google.com","google.com","yahoo.com","bing.com","yahoo.com") ,col2= c("dog", "cat", "hamster", "dog","cat","cat","dog","cat")))
     bevs
     library(plyr)

     tab<-count(bevs, c("col1", "col2"))
     r=matrix(NA,length(levels(tab$col1)),length(levels(tab$col2)))
     rownames(r)=levels(tab$col1)
     colnames(r)=levels(tab$col2)

     for(i in levels(tab$col1))
     {
       for(j in levels(tab$col2))
       {

                if(length(tab$freq[tab$col1==i&tab$col2==j])==0)
                r[i,j]=0
                else
                r[i,j]=tab$freq[tab$col1==i&tab$col2==j]  
       }

     }

    r
```

Output:

```
          cat dog hamster
bing.com     0   1       1
google.com   1   2       0
yahoo.com    3   0       0
```

Find the code here http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=BveQws3p&version=10

Comment: Can someone please explain what is the problem with my answer. A comment will be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Some people may not like the non-brevity of your code (compare it to some other answers here and in the vote-closed link).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback .I agree it is not concise. So should I be removing it?